# Open-XML-SDK not reporting errors in documents that Word fails to open

Tags: validation, ms-word, openxml-sdk

When opening a test Word document I see the following Error:

[image: Error opening Word Document]

However, when validating the same document using "Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office", the error is not shown at all.

Thinking this may be due to 2.5 being a bit old, I cloned and compiled the latest [Open-XML-SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) GIT repository and then ran a programatic validation. Still the error remains undetected.

This validation inconsistency is a real problem for me so if anyone can point me to a tool / method that validates in a a way synonymous with the way Word validates I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Would you mind sharing your document somewhere?

Comment: Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298785/openxml-table-error-p-elements-are-required-before-every-tc for an explanation on what is going on.

Comment: thanks @DirkVollmar - I'm 100% on the cause of the problem ie. that in document.xml there is no <w:p> at the appropriate location inside <w:tc> and we are able to resolve it. What I don't understand - maybe I was misunderstanding - and didn't see explained in the link is why the Open-XML-SDK schema implementation doesn't reflect the document.xml error in the same way.

Comment: @DirkVollmar - while I can't share the original document I have replicated the error in a very simple equivalent that I can send to you with pleasure. Please let me know how and I'll get it off to you

Comment: Hi @Pancho - if you post it to github and share the link here, we can try and find a solution to this problem.  In the end, users with this similar problem will benefit from the solution.