# Unreadable Word document after removing cell borders (OpenXml.Wordprocessing)

Tags: c#, openxml, wordprocessingml

After creating a `TableCellProperties` and removing the `TableCellBorders`, the word document becomes unreadable and I get:

> Word found unreadable content in test.docx. Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source of this document, click Yes.

The code that I use:

```
TableCellProperties cellProp = new TableCellProperties(
    new TableCellBorders(
        new TopBorder()
        {
            Val =
                new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Nil),
        },
        new BottomBorder()
        {
            Val =
                new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Nil),
        },
        new LeftBorder()
        {
            Val =
                new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Nil),

        },
        new RightBorder()
        {
            Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Nil),
        }
    )
);
TableCell tc = new TableCell();


tc.Append(cellProp);

TableRow trTest = new TableRow();
trTest.Append(new TableCell(tc.OuterXml));
trTest.Append(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("B")))));
trTest.Append(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("C")))));
trTest.Append(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("D")))));
trTest.Append(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("E")))));
trTest.Append(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("F")))));
t.Append(trTest);
```

The `BorderValue` is set to `Nil`, since `None` does not seem to remove the borders. After the MS Word auto recover procedure, the file is fine. Whan can cause such an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Each table cell should contain/end with `Paragraph` object, so the solution is:

```
tc.Append(cellProp);
tc.Append(new Paragraph());
```

Looks like I have the same problem like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298785/openxml-table-error-p-elements-are-required-before-every-tc?rq=1), but without the error.